# Convert a pdb file in a csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am Cosimo from Italy, I am a student of physical chemistry, i am doing my thesis and i have a big problem.
I nead to convert a pdb file in a csv for work with pandas.
I've tried every way but with no success.
Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with pdb files, but after a quick search I found this :

http://rasbt.github.io/biopandas/tutorials/Working_with_PDB_Structures_in_DataFrames/

It seems like you can read the pdb file as a dataframe, then you can convert dataframe to csv by using `df.to_csv()`